# Wait to run Javascript after all partials are loaded on a page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

The application I'm working on is an internal business application for managers. It's a C# web application. The main office has an instance of this app running and it always has the latest version. Each store has it's own instance of the application running as well, but may not always have the latest version. A manager logs in to the main office app and then selects a store to view. That store's instance is pulled up in the main part of the app, the upper menu bar is from the main office's instance. Thus, it is possible that the main office has v1.8 and a store to have v1.7.

There are some features in 1.8 that show up on the menu bar that are not present in 1.7 that I would like to hide. The main page has multiple partials that get loaded and the very last partial has the specific store's version number that is determined by the code on that store's server. Because of this, the only way to get the version number is to get it after it is rendered on the page. The main problem I'm having is that the Javascript I'm using to hide the links to the new features is running before the partial with the version number loads.

I need the Javascript to wait until the entire page finishes loading to execute the hiding code. Also, the application is only run in Chrome.

Here is the code I've got to hide the links:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    if ($('.version').length !== 0) {
        if (parseFloat($('.version').text().slice(5)) > 1.7) {
            $('.analysis').show();
        } else {
            $('.analysis').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How are the partials loaded? By AJAX?

Comment: They are being loaded by _ViewStart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading the partial with ajax on the client side explicitly, you can just add a complete function to call:

```
$( "#storeContainer" ).load( "url/for/partial", function () {
  if ($('.version').length !== 0) {
    if (parseFloat($('.version').text().slice(5)) > 1.7) {
      $('.analysis').show();
    } else {
      $('.analysis').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Of course, you'll probably want the "url/for/partial" to use @Url.Content or @Url.Action if you can.

If you are using The Ajax Helper, you can set the OnSuccess property of your AjaxOptions to call you back:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Refresh", 
    "Store", 
     new AjaxOptions { 
         HttpMethod = "POST", 
         UpdateTargetId = "storeContainer", 
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
         OnSuccess = "updateSuccess" });
```

where you have defined your OnSuccess function in javascript:

```
var updateSuccess = function () {
  if ($('.version').length !== 0) {
    if (parseFloat($('.version').text().slice(5)) > 1.7) {
      $('.analysis').show();
    } else {
      $('.analysis').hide();
    }
  }
```

There are some other ideas about how to include the script in your partial view or call it during your ajax success event on [How to initialize jquery ui widgets that may be loaded dynamically in MVC3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800204/how-to-initialize-jquery-ui-widgets-that-may-be-loaded-dynamically-in-mvc3-appli)

If you were using Asp.net AJAX, you could use `Sys.Application.add_load(function(){...})`.

Comment: It's an MVC3 application.

Comment: Also I can't include it in the partial view because the partial that is being loaded is on the store's server, and it is an older version of the application.

Comment: Including in the partial view probably isn't an option for you. However, the link shows how to use the ajax success also. It also shows "unobtrusive behaviors" which is probably the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I updated the answer with examples of how to add a callback function for when the partial is loaded.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the partials are being loaded using _ViewStart. How would that change what I could do?

Comment: Hmmm. I am not sure what that would look like. Can you be more specific? Show some code? If it is not there on the window.load event, you have to be using ajax somewhere. Can you update you question with the line of code that is used to include the partial on the page? Are you using an ajax helper (@Ajax....) or are you using a client-side script? Or is there some third way? Wherever you are adding the partial (the line of code) there will be somewhere to register a callback for when the content is loaded, unless it is  server side, in which case the problem is not when the code is called

Comment: I finally found where we were doing it in Ajax and what you posted worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {

});
```

in place of $window.load()?

Comment: `$(window).load` triggers the function when all the content (images, fonts) is downloaded, `$(document).ready` triggers BEFORE it, just when the document is ready - so all images and fonts have not been downloaded yet.